# Converting Naive UTC to Aware UTC, why use replace() over localize()?

Tags: python, datetime, pytz

Say I have a naive datetime object `dt`, which is a UTC timestamp (with no tzinfo).

One can make it aware in one of 2 ways:

- `pytz.UTC.localize(dt, is_dst=None)`
- `dt.replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)`

This link [Date time conversion table](http://taaviburns.ca/presentations/what_you_need_to_know_about_datetimes/) recommends using `replace()`. This only works if the naive datetime object is in UTC (and not a local time). However I feel its all to easy for bugs to creep in by applying the same methodology on none UTC timestamps.

If one went with `localize()`, no bugs would be introduced by changing the timezone to a local tzinfo object.

The only advantage I can guess is that probably the `replace()` is faster. Does anyone know why `replace()` is recommended over method `localize()`? I plan to just use `localize()` for consistency but hope I am not missing something.

The recommended duplicate post by @deceze focusses on why .replace does not work on none UTC datetimes, which this post is not about. This post is about if it is in UTC, .replace with work, but why favour it.

Comment: `replace`, as the name says, basically just replaces one part of the object with another value. *If you know what you're doing* and that is sufficient (as is the case with UTC), then yeah, it's the simplest thing that works. But as you say yourself, it can lead to errors. So, pick wisely.

Comment: @deceze I don't think it is a duplicate question to the question you already answered. They are on the same topic but do not have the same answer. This comment however is useful.

Comment: Well, the deciding sentence there is *"`replace` == dumb, simply overwrite raw data"*. Again, if you know what you're doing, that may be okay. It's debatable whether you should ever *favour* it.

Comment: "It's debatable whether you should ever favour it", well the author, who presented that material at PyCon, does favour it, and that what this post is about, why.

Comment: On his [slides](http://taaviburns.ca/presentations/what_you_need_to_know_about_datetimes/what_you_need_to_know_about_datetimes.pdf) `.replace` is actually listed under ***Don't***, so… ‍♂️